# Recommendation to build a corporate website with CMS

Tags: javascript, web-development, programming

I need help in the following problem, but some relevant context. I studied as a software engineer in college and learned mainly Java, C, and some JS. After I graduated, my first job was at a low-code company, so I never had the opportunity to explore and improve my skills in frameworks and so on, in a more corporate or professional way.

Having this in mind, the problem is, I'm building a corporate site, the purpose is to show the company image, who they are, and all the projects they have worked on (in a form of a gallery).

So this website doesn't have any logic or isn't even really complex, but one of the requirements is, the content has to be managed in a backoffice. They also want to be owners of their code. They already have a website but is very old and they couldn't manage any content without a developer's intervention. They also own the server and domain.

So the main point here is so I can learn, practice and grow myself while building a great solution for the customer.

What technologies do you advise facing all this?

Comment: Woocommerce plugin for Wordpress is fine. Also Joomla has a plugin named Virtuemart. If you're good at php and error handling then Oscommerce is great. When using CMS' I always set cache and tmp folders permissions to 777.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the current content management systems will enable you to do this and also own the code since mostly open source. Some of the options I recommend you look at include:

- [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/): open-source, php-based
- [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/): open-source, php-based
- [Liferay](http://liferay.com/): java-based

Pleas see here for a comparison of [various CMS](http://www.cmsmatrix.org/).

Comment: Since there is no logic required wouldn’t a static site generator be an appropriate option? Perhaps simpler and safer?

Comment: Could be but see above:  "but one of the requirements is, the content have to be manage in a backoffice"...

Comment: Which is allowed by most static site generators, I believe. Jekyl in particular seems nice. https://cloudcannon.com/jekyll-cms/?utm_source=google-ads&utm_campaign=CMSseo&utm_term=jekyll%20cms&utm_medium=Search&utm_content=JekyllCMS&gclid=CjwKCAjwieuGBhAsEiwA1Ly_nfAVfAfCMuXR1Rv-me8eEAZAOVhSJXfxl1E5G--U0_Z0uUE8dQYj6xoCUg0QAvD_BwE

Comment: Why not add it as an answer? If you are part of the team, pls declare so.Not used it myself.

Comment: I’ve only played with it and never used it beyond a local instance. Just asking as you seem much more experienced than I am.